# jquery validation rules dependency

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using this example from Validation Plug-in's 'required (dependency-expression)' explanation:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    details: {
      required: "#other:checked"
    }
  }, debug:true
});
$("#other").click(function() {
    $("#details").valid();
});
```

I'm trying to make the text input required if radio button #guide is selected in example below:

```
<input type="radio" id="outfitter" name="memtype" value="Outfitter" />Outfitter $125
<input type="radio" id="guide" name="memtype" value="Guide" />Guide $75
<input type="text" id="sponout" name="sponout" size="75" />
```

I just don't know where to place

```
 $("#other").click(function() {
    $("#details").valid();
 });
```

within rules validation coding.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you could do this:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        sponout: {
            required: "#guide:checked"
        }
    }
});

$("input[name='memtype']").change(function () {
    $("#myform").valid();
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kqczf/1/

Comment: OK, gotcha.  I'll give 'er a whirl.  Thanx, particularly for the fiddle example.

Comment: Dropped final '.change function' code section and worked fine.  Realized I could simply add required:"condition terms" as you pointed out, Andrew.